# Discord.js bot can't send message to specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot send a message to a specific channel on Discord. However, when I use the command it results in an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined .

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'send',
    description: 'sends a message testing',
    execute(client) {
        const channel01 = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "768667222527705148");
        channel01.send('Hi');
    },
};
```

In my index.js file, I have the following in the beginning, so I don't think the client usage in front of .channels is the problem.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
```

Here's my Index.js file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity("KevinYT", {
        type: "WATCHING",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUr50quaTjBKWL1fLuWRvCg?view_as=subscriber"
      });
});

client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }

    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose your `client` is not an instance of client itself.. Can you send the command handler of getting this `send` file?

Comment: I added my index.js file to the initial question. I believe the command handler starts at line  8 or 27.

Comment: Like Arun Kumar Mohan said, you are passing `message` and `args` as parameters but in this file you are passing client. The parameters have to be the same and also in same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
command.execute(message, args)
```

You're passing the `execute` function `message` (a [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object) as the first argument but you're trying to use it as a [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) object. The code fails since `message.channels` is `undefined` (the confusion arises from the argument name used in the `execute` function).

You can use [`message.client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) to get access to the [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) object.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  execute (message) {
    const channel01 = message.client.channels.cache.find(
      (channel) => channel.id === '768667222527705148'
    )
    // ...
  },
}
```